# How to add another condition when using groupby.nth in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a set of `df` as below:

[image]

Each member has a unique Member Code. My aim is to extract the 1st and 5th visits of every day of every member into a new data frame without using `for loop`. Any ideas how should I do that?

Part of the sample data on 2018-09-02 is:
[image]

I tried to use: `df.groupby(df["DateTime"].dt.date).nth([0,4])`
but the output is :

[image]

As you can see, the third and the fifth row are from the same member. Since the member are the same, so how should I do in order to take the next member which is row number 153 with member code 17753?

Here is the small dataframe as an example:

```
DateTime = ["2018-09-01 00:01:00","2018-09-01 00:35:00","2018-09-01 01:14:00","2018-09-01 01:39:00","2018-09-01 01:46:00",
            "2018-09-02 00:13:00","2018-09-02 00:51:00","2018-09-02 01:23:00","2018-09-02 02:06:00","2018-09-02 02:16:00"]
Duration = [3.0,14.0,9.0,15.0,7.5,1.0,2.0,8.0,3.0,10.0]
Member_Code = [13595,17630,13522,17630,14942,17022,13596,10785,13596,14942]
data = {"DateTime":DateTime, "Duration":Duration, "Member Code":Member_Code}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["DateTime"], format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")

df1
```

So based on this example, I want to extract the 2nd and the 4th visit. So, the expected output should be a dataframe consists of the rows with indexes of 1,3,6 and 9 (since the member in row with index 8 is the same as the row with index 6)

**EDITED:**

DataFrame:

```
DateTime = ["2018-09-01 00:01:00","2018-09-01 00:35:00","2018-09-01 01:14:00","2018-09-01 01:39:00","2018-09-01 01:46:00",
            "2018-09-02 00:13:00","2018-09-02 00:51:00","2018-09-02 01:23:00","2018-09-02 02:06:00","2018-09-02 02:16:00"]
Duration = [3.0,14.0,9.0,15.0,7.5,1.0,2.0,8.0,3.0,10.0]
Member_Code = [13595,17630,13522,17630,14942,17022,13596,13596,13596,14942]
data = {"DateTime":DateTime, "Duration":Duration, "Member Code":Member_Code}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["DateTime"], format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")

df1
```

Solution:

```
vals = [1, 2]
df_new = df1.groupby(df1["DateTime"].dt.date).nth(vals)
dates = df1["DateTime"].dt.date
mask = df1['Member Code'].eq(dates.map(df1['Member Code'].groupby(dates).nth(vals[1])))
mask1 = df1['Member Code'].groupby(dates).cumcount().ne(vals[0])
df = df1.mask(mask & mask1).groupby(dates).bfill()
df_new = df.groupby(df1["DateTime"].dt.date).nth(vals)
df_new
```

Answer:

```
              DateTime            DateTime  Duration  Member Code
DateTime                                                         
2018-09-01  2018-09-01 2018-09-01 00:35:00      14.0      17630.0
2018-09-01  2018-09-01 2018-09-01 01:39:00      15.0      17630.0
2018-09-02  2018-09-02 2018-09-02 00:51:00       2.0      13596.0
2018-09-02  2018-09-02 2018-09-02 02:16:00      10.0      14942.0
```

Comment: Is possible create expected output from sample data? I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I tried o use `df_new = df.groupby(df["DateTime"].dt.date).nth([0,4])` but unfortunately the 5th visit on 2018-09-02 is the same as the 1st visit. So I'm not sure how to choose the next member instead of taking the same member.

Comment: Any idea on how to deal with this problem?

Comment: hmmm, so problem is in data which are not in sample data in question? Also it seems is necessary test code with your data, what is problem, because picture. So is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it means data with problem in text with expected output?

Comment: I had edited the question and show the output of `df_new = df.groupby(df["DateTime"].dt.date).nth([0,4])`, it should be clear on what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for `1/3` required info. Still missing input sample data for `2018-09-02` in text (still all data re pictures), missing expected output which is correct for `2018-09-02`.

Comment: I had added another picture again, hope it is clear:)

Comment: unfortunately not understand why not `10785` is used for 5th row for `2018-09-02`.

Comment: ya should be `10785`, Sorry, I make a mistake here. Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: yes, I can help you. Only need second picture in text. I cannot copy data from picture to dataframe.[Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Some problem copy dataframe data like text?

Comment: I had created a mini dataframe for as an example, please let me know if you need any other information:)

Comment: Now it is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
DateTime = ["2018-09-01 00:01:00","2018-09-01 00:35:00","2018-09-01 01:14:00","2018-09-01 01:39:00","2018-09-01 01:46:00",
            "2018-09-02 00:13:00","2018-09-02 00:51:00","2018-09-02 01:23:00","2018-09-02 02:06:00","2018-09-02 02:16:00"]
Duration = [3.0,14.0,9.0,15.0,7.5,1.0,2.0,8.0,3.0,10.0]
Member_Code = [13595,17630,13522,17630,14942,17022,13596,13596,13596,14942]
data = {"DateTime":DateTime, "Duration":Duration, "Member Code":Member_Code}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["DateTime"], format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
print (df1)
             DateTime  Duration  Member Code
0 2018-09-01 00:01:00       3.0        13595
1 2018-09-01 00:35:00      14.0        17630
2 2018-09-01 01:14:00       9.0        13522
3 2018-09-01 01:39:00      15.0        17630
4 2018-09-01 01:46:00       7.5        14942
5 2018-09-02 00:13:00       1.0        17022
6 2018-09-02 00:51:00       2.0        13596
7 2018-09-02 01:23:00       8.0        13596
8 2018-09-02 02:06:00       3.0        13596
9 2018-09-02 02:16:00      10.0        14942
```

First compare `Member Code` of first `nth` value by all values of column per groups to `mask` and also exclude first `nth` value by test by counter with `cumcount`, pass to [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and back filling missing values per groups, last use original solution:

```
vals = [1, 2]
dates = df1["DateTime"].dt.date
mask = df1['Member Code'].eq(dates.map(df1['Member Code'].groupby(dates).nth(vals[0])))
mask1 = df1['Member Code'].groupby(dates).cumcount().ne(vals[0])
df = df1.mask(mask & mask1).groupby(dates).bfill()
print (df)
             DateTime  Duration  Member Code
0 2018-09-01 00:01:00       3.0      13595.0
1 2018-09-01 00:35:00      14.0      17630.0
2 2018-09-01 01:14:00       9.0      13522.0
3 2018-09-01 01:46:00       7.5      14942.0
4 2018-09-01 01:46:00       7.5      14942.0
5 2018-09-02 00:13:00       1.0      17022.0
6 2018-09-02 00:51:00       2.0      13596.0
7 2018-09-02 02:16:00      10.0      14942.0
8 2018-09-02 02:16:00      10.0      14942.0
9 2018-09-02 02:16:00      10.0      14942.0

df_new = df.groupby(df1["DateTime"].dt.date).nth(vals)
print (df_new)
                      DateTime  Duration  Member Code
DateTime                                             
2018-09-01 2018-09-01 00:35:00      14.0      17630.0
2018-09-01 2018-09-01 01:14:00       9.0      13522.0
2018-09-02 2018-09-02 00:51:00       2.0      13596.0
2018-09-02 2018-09-02 02:16:00      10.0      14942.0
```

Comment: Jezrael, thanks for your reply! However, I'm not sure the the use of `groupby(dates)` in the `eq()` function. Further, if I want to compare the second value to the other in the same group what is the function that I should use in the `transform()`? Appreciate your advice!

Comment: @Elvis - So need instead `df1['Member Code'].groupby(dates).transform('first')` get second values to groups like `df1['Member Code'].groupby(dates).transform(lambda x: x.iat[1])` ?

Comment: @jezrael- I just realized that there should be some error in your `df_new`. By right, the `member code` for the 3rd row should be 17022 instead of 13596. I think this is because the `bfill()` backfilled the `True` value based on `mask` which caused the row with 17022 been backfilled by 13596. How should I deal with this problem where the code is still reproducible? Thanks!

Comment: @Elvis - I understand now, answer was edited for exclude back filling first rows per groups.

Comment: @ jezrael - Based on your data, the solution you provided is perfect. However, if I used my own data, it doesn't work for me. I had edited the data where this time I want to extract the 2nd and the 4th visit instead of the one you provide (1st and 3rd visit) for everyday. The code seems like unable to reuse again even I add the `mask1`. Do you have any solution where the code is reproducible?

Comment: @Elvis - There need also change `transform('first')` for match by second groups, answer was edited.

Comment: @jezrael- Your general solution seems like doesn't work for me. I had edited my question with an extra edited session, and using the solution you provided, but the `Member Code` for 1st and 2nd row are still the same (initially it doesn't have any problem, after apply `mask & mask 1, the problem appear). I also attached my answer for your reference. Hope to get your advise!

Comment: @Elvis - There was problem compared by second `nth` insted first, so need change `mask = df1['Member Code'].eq(dates.map(df1['Member Code'].groupby(dates).nth(vals[1])))` to `mask = df1['Member Code'].eq(dates.map(df1['Member Code'].groupby(dates).nth(vals[0])))`, thank you for patience

Comment: @jezrael- Really appreciate your help in these few days! I finally got it! May I know why  you use the `cumcount()` and `ne()` in `mask1`? I understand the meaning for these two function individually but not really clear what you mean by `exclude first nth value by test by counter with cumcount` . Thanks!

Comment: @Elvis - sure, I can explain. Reson is avoid rewritten first `nth` values, so Is used counter per groups for get first nth row and is compare by first nth from list by not equal for not replace to NaNs (so never back filled by `df1.mask(mask & mask1).groupby(dates).bfill()`)

Comment: @jezrael- really thanks for your input! Can you give me an advise where I can learn more about all these data manipulations/cleaning methods in python? Any online course or books that I can learn from?

Comment: @Elvis - Foe me working 3 year everyday coding.... Not easy path :(